# Swift How to send different notifications in 2 week intervals

Tags: ios, swift

I am a new swift programmer and wanted to create a schedule app. 
After doing a bit more research, I concluded that making 80 separate notifications and putting them on a 2 week interval repeat would be the easiest option for me.
Unfortunately I found you could not make custom repeat intervals, but that there were a few loopholes. I was wondering if there were any for my case

Any help would be appreciated

PS sorry for posing many broad questions

Comment: Your question is way too broad. You can find about local (and remote) notifications here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1

Comment: I have looked through the your link, but unfortunately I haven't found a desired answer

Comment: I do apologise for the broadness of my question and I hope this rephrase can sum it up better; Is it possible for a function (as the one above) to send a local notification? Most examples of a local notification seem to be issued from the from the difference of time between the current time and the time until the notification. I want to know if there is a function that can change this amount depending on what day it is.

Comment: Actually, when you set up a local notification, you define the actual date time of the notification, not the time interval until the notification. Check out the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/fireDate

Comment: hmm, so If I could make a function that could change the numbers to send the notifications to a set time for each week, this would succeed...

Comment: The new formulation of your question is probably even worse than the previous one.